# Нормативно ли повторение частицы «бы» при «если» и при глаголе?

Tags: синтаксис, стилистика, морфология, придаточное-предложение, частицы

В «Русской грамматике» 1980 г. сказано (§ 3001):

> Допустимо повторение частицы ***бы*** при ***если*** и при глаголе:
> *Если бы Нехлюдов тогда ясно осознал бы свою любовь к Катюше и в особенности если бы тогда его стали бы убеждать в том, что он никак не может и не должен соединить свою судьбу с такой девушкой, то очень легко могло бы случиться, что он... решил бы, что нет никаких причин не жениться на девушке, кто бы она ни была* (Л. Толст.); *Если бы стекла было на земле так же мало, как алмазов, и, наоборот, если бы алмазов было бы так же много, как стекла, то, конечно, стекло бы ценилось на вес золота* (Пауст.).

Розенталь же пишет, что такое употребление не соответствует норме.

> 3. Неправильное употребление союзов и союзных слов проявляется в различных случаях:
>    д) повторение частицы *бы* в придаточных предложениях, в которых сказуемое выражено глаголом в форме условно-сослагательного наклонения (получаются сочетания *чтобы... бы*, *если бы... бы*), например: *Было выражено пожелание, чтобы контакты, установившиеся между российскими и американскими предпринимателями, получили бы свое дальнейшее развитие*; *Если бы предложения западных держав были бы приняты, положение могло бы измениться*. Такие конструкции придают высказыванию разговорный характер. Ср.: *Мне надо, чтобы каждое слово, каждая фраза попадала бы в тон, к месту* (Короленко)...

Так допустимо или нет? Что пишут другие справочники (если они, конечно, что-то об этом пишут)?

Comment: Мне кажется, что вот в этом варианте все хорошо, приемлемо: _Ах, если бы сбылась моя мечта, какая жизнь настала бы тогда! Ах, если бы мечта сбылась, какая жизнь тогда бы началась!_ (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ay55eQhvVHA)

Comment: Текст — Юрия Энтина. В советское время (1980, кажется) —детям? с ошибками? — не пропустили бы! А характер? Конечно же, разговорный, сказочный.

Answer (score 2):

Источник* (Шведова, 1980), в котором говорится допустимости того, что у Розенталя трактуется как характерная ошибка, позиционирован не как нормативный, а как *описательный* (*"Книга построена на материалах, извлеченных из разнообразных по жанрам письменных источников, а также на материалах разговорной литературной речи"*); приведённые же в нём примеры из литературы свидетельствуют о том, что такое допускалось корректорами де-факто и в этом смысле "допустимо".

В одном из *исследовательских* источников** (Добрушина, 2016) примеры с повторением "**бы**" при "**если**" не приводились вообще (несмотря на подробнейшую классификацию случаев употребления частицы), а о практической встречаемости "**бы**" в сочетании со "**чтобы**" упомянуто лишь в связи с авторским исследованием вопроса: "всегда ли **чтобы** несёт в себе частицу **бы** как признак сослагательного наклонения" (если не всегда, то добавленная говорящим частица **бы** указывает на то, что элемент **бы** в составе **чтобы** не воспринимается им как признак сослагательности - при конкретном контексте):

> ... очень хочется, **чтобы** энергии Магомета Толбоева **хватило бы**, чтобы
>   одолеть и эту проблему.

Автором найдено (с. 266), что допустимо добалять к **чтобы** частицу **бы** при втором предикате (если он имеется) в подчинённой части предложения - как упрощённое повторение "**чтобы**", и только в прошедшем времени:

> Дмитрий  Павлович, когда он за рулём, предпочтает, **чтобы звучало**
>   радио и не **звучала бы** Тамара.

По всей видимости, вопрос о повторной частице "**бы**" при "**если**" у автора (книга Шведовой ему знакома и упоминалась) даже не стоял (частица **бы** пишется отдельно от **если**), поэтому **не** видно оснований говорить о *нормативности* рассматриваемого здесь более широкого допущения.

*Н. Ю. ШВЕДОВА. Русская грамматика. Том II. Синтаксис. Наука , Москва, 1980.
http://scicenter.online/yazyik-russkiy-scicenter/russkaya-grammatika-tom-sintaksis-izdatelstvo.html

** Н. Р. Добрушина. Сослагательное наклонение в русском языке. Москва, 2016
https://books.google.ru/books?id=GZ5-DQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

***Н. Р. Добрушина. Семантика косвенного наклонения, докт. диссертация 2016
http://www.ruslang.ru/doc/diss/dobrushina.pdf

Comment: Но ведь в предисловии к этой книге написано: «Издаваемая сейчас "Русская грамматика" является описательной и нормативной. Она ставит своей задачей совместить научное описание грамматического строя современного русского литературного языка с нормативными рекомендациями и оценками.

Comment: Таким образом, попытки решения теоретических вопросов и научная систематизация фактов соединяются здесь с задачами нормативными: книга содержит сведения о том, какие возможности словообразования, формы слов, их акцентные характеристики, синтаксические конструкции являются для современного состояния русского литературного языка единственно правильными и какие – вариативными (допускаемыми в употреблении наряду с другими, равнозначными или близкими по значениям).

Comment: С решением нормативных задач связано введение во все разделы "Русской грамматики" стилистических и других специализирующих характеристик».

Comment: Если в качестве нормативной рекомендации рассматривать то, что касается повторного _бы_ при _если_, то я бы разрешением "допустить" не воспользовался: возможно, во времена написания примеров это было допустимо, но в современном языке это звучит небезупречно, и рекомендации Розенталя мне ближе. Необходимости же исходить из такого "разрешения" нет - сам я так никогда не говорю, не пишу и сразу замечаю в тексте как шероховатость.

Comment: Учитывая, что последнее издание справочника Розенталя выпущено в 1999 году (а последнее прижизненное вообще в 1967-м), а «Русская грамматика» издана в 1980-м, не думаю, что за 19 лет всё так сильно поменялось. Всё-таки первая книга посвящена больше стилистике, а вторая — грамматике, поэтому, скорее всего, повторение этой частицы допустимо, но лучше этого не делать.

Comment: Я имею в виду возраст цитат из Толстого и Короленко (современные случаи склонен считать примерами ошибок). Книга же Розенталя, из которой ссылка, называется так: _Справочник по **правописанию**, произношению, литературному редактированию_. Д.Э. Розенталь, Е.В. Джанджакова, Н.П. Кабанова; название параграфа 210: "**Ошибки** в сложных предложениях".

Comment: Текст параграфа: https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091284.html#id-47%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%C2%A7210%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85